# SUM two Columns with where, group and having

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables. One is called `Documents` and the other is called `Payments` I want to be able to `Group` all rows by `Documents.InvoiceNumber` and I want to be able to `SUM` all records from `Payments` that have the same `Document.InvoiceNumber` to their `Mode`.

For example in `Documents` I have these rows:

```
---------------------------------
|ID      |Acct  |InvoiceNumber  |
---------------------------------
|27509   |68213 |0000024383     |
---------------------------------
|27508   |68396 |0000024383     |
---------------------------------
|27507   |68418 |0000024382     |
---------------------------------
```

And in `Payments` I have these rows:

```
------------------------------------
|ID     |Acct  |OperType|Qtty |Mode|
------------------------------------
|156396 |68396 |2       |43.89|1   |
------------------------------------
|156389 |68418 |2       |36.96|1   |
------------------------------------
|156314 |68418 |2       |36.96|-1  |
------------------------------------
|156265 |68213 |2       |52.25|1   |
------------------------------------
|156264 |68396 |2       |43.89|-1  |
------------------------------------
|155895 |68213 |2       |52.25|-1  |
------------------------------------
```

I want to be able to check if

> InvoiceNumber -> Payments.Mode = -1 -> SUM(Qtty) is equal to InvoiceNumber -> Payments.Mode = 1 -> SUM(Qtty)

For example:

```
Invoice Number = 0000024383 | Mode = -1 | Qtty = 96.14
Invoice Number = 0000024383 | Mode =  1 | Qtty = 96.14
```

And I want to be able to check in mysql statement if those two are the same or not, and I want to be able to output only the records that are NOT the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I followed you correctly, you should be able to solve this using *conditional aggregation* :

```
SELECT 
    d.invoicenumber,
    SUM(CASE WHEN p.mode = -1 THEN p.qtty ELSE 0 END) qtty_minus1,
    SUM(CASE WHEN p.mode = 1 THEN p.qtty ELSE 0 END) qtty1
FROM 
    Documents d
    INNER JOIN Payments p ON p.acct = d.acct
GROUP BY 
    d.invoicenumber
HAVING 
    SUM(CASE WHEN p.mode = -1 THEN p.qtty ELSE 0 END) 
    <> SUM(CASE WHEN p.mode = 1 THEN p.qtty ELSE 0 END)
```

The query aggregates records by invoice number, and then compares the total quantity of records where mode is `-1` to the total quantity of records where mode is `1`. The `HAVING` clause ensures that only invoice numbers for which the total quantities differ are displayed in the results.

See **[this DB Fiddle demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/cYesbAB9ntKoY6CLXJ1oQK/3)**: I had to alter your sample data since it did not have offending records.

```
| invoicenumber | qtty_minus1 | qtty1 |
| ------------- | ----------- | ----- |
| 0000024383    | 96.13       | 96.14 |
```